# Autocompletion elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm following along with the tutorial for elasticsearch's completion suggester [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html). It's pretty easy to get going. But I'm unable to get completions for more than one word. In the example single incomplete words give great results, e.g

`"Nir"` -> `"options":[{"text":"Nevermind Nirvana..."`

`"Nev"` -> `"options":[{"text":"Nevermind Nirvana..."`

But the following fail:

`"Nirvana Nev"` -> `Nothing!`

`"Nevermind Nir"` -> `Nothing!`

I can get it to work by populating combinatorial options e.g

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/music/_doc/1?refresh" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana", "Nirvana Nevermind", "Nevermind Nirvana" ],
        "weight" : 34
    },
    "title" : "Nevermind by Nirvana"
}
'
```

But this approach will soon lead to massive variants of text added to the input.

There must be a better way?